# How to set a string as array and set array maximum

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to make an array with the same value and set the array to be maximum based on my counter.

For example, I want to create an array with a string "hello" and I want it to keep going until the number of array is 3.

How is that possible using php with yii2 framework?

Comment: Show your efforts and return with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a for loop this way

```
$array= array();
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
   $array[] = "hello";
}
```

You will get $array with 3 hello.

Answer (score 0):

try [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

```
$count = 5;
$a = array_fill(0, $count, 'hello');
```